# WilFly Cluster and JSESSIONID

Tags: java, wildfly, load-balancing, infinispan

I have a Java application running on WildFly 25 on AWS. We are trying to set up High Availability with two nodes using Infinispan cache to replicate the session between nodes.

**web.xml**

```
<!-- cluster-aware -->
<distributable/>
```

**distributable-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<distributable-web xmlns="urn:jboss:distributable-web:2.0">
    <infinispan-session-management cache-container="web" cache="corpapp-session-cache-web" granularity="SESSION">
        <no-affinity/>
    </infinispan-session-management>
</distributable-web>
```

**standalone-ha.xml**

```
  <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
    <distributed-cache name="corpapp-session-cache-web">
      <file-store path="corpapp-cache" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="false"/>
    </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
```

Start each node:

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0;
```

Sticky session is enabled.

We basically followed this: https://octopus.com/blog/wildfly-jdbc-ping

The cache is written to the file system as expected. When a user stays on one node, the session is valid, however as soon as a user moves to a different node the session is not replicated and a new session is created nullifying the point of what we are  trying to achieve by caching the session.

The article says the the JSESSIONID should be the same for each node. However, when I check in the browser it is different depending on what node the user is on, i.e. it appends the node name (`prod-nexct-app01` or `prod-nexct-app02` the JSESSIONID).

e.g.

[image]

**Question**

1. should the JSESSIONID be the same for both nodes?
2. If so, how do I achieve this?